# Different navigation bar behaviour between CABTMIDILocalPeripheralViewController and CABTMIDICentralViewController

Tags: ios, objective-c

I am struggling to understand why the following views, one for CABTMIDILocalPeripheralViewController and the other for CABTMIDICentralViewController show different behaviour in my iOS app (written in Objective-C)

```
- (IBAction)configureCentral:(id)sender 
{
CABTMIDICentralViewController *viewController = [CABTMIDICentralViewController new];
UINavigationController *navController = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:viewController]; // this will present a view controller as a popover in iPad and modal VC on iPhone

viewController.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemDone
                                              target:self
                                              action:@selector(doneAction:)];

navController.modalPresentationStyle = UIModalPresentationPopover;

UIPopoverPresentationController *popC = navController.popoverPresentationController;

popC.permittedArrowDirections = UIPopoverArrowDirectionAny;
popC.sourceRect = [sender frame];

viewController.preferredContentSize = CGSizeMake(320., 400.);

popC.backgroundColor = [UIColor darkGrayColor];
viewController.view.backgroundColor = [UIColor darkGrayColor];

UIButton *button = (UIButton *)sender;
popC.sourceView = button.superview;

[self presentViewController:navController animated:NO completion:nil];
}
```

Opens a popup view on an iOS device, which does not show any 'done' button to dismiss the view.

[CABTMIDICentralViewController shows no button to close/dismiss the view](https://i.stack.imgur.com/C8KJq.png)

While on an iPad tapping outside the view will close it, on an iPhone the view takes the size of the screen and exiting/closing becomes impossible.

The same code used for the CABTMIDILocalPeripheralViewController works as expected.

```
- (IBAction)configureLocalPeripheral:(id)sender
{
    CABTMIDILocalPeripheralViewController *vController = [[CABTMIDILocalPeripheralViewController alloc] init];
    UINavigationController *navController = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:vController];

    vController.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemDone
                                                                               target:self
                                                                               action:@selector(doneWithPeripheral:)];

    navController.modalPresentationStyle = UIModalPresentationPopover;

    UIPopoverPresentationController *popC = navController.popoverPresentationController;
    popC.permittedArrowDirections = UIPopoverArrowDirectionAny;
    popC.sourceRect = [sender frame];

    vController.preferredContentSize = CGSizeMake(320., 400.);

    popC.backgroundColor = [UIColor grayColor];
    vController.view.backgroundColor = [UIColor darkGrayColor];

    UIButton *button = (UIButton *)sender;
    popC.sourceView = button.superview;

    [self presentViewController:navController animated:NO completion:nil];
}
```

[CABTMIDILocalPeripheralViewController has a 'done' button](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4BYWM.png)

What is going wrong here? I have tested to make the views wider to see whether available space in the Navigation bar would have caused this.

Thanks.

Comment: If you click on "iPhone" for the `CABTMIDICentralViewController`, does it dismiss the view controller? I'm wondering because the local one, doesn't have any action (either changing name or allowing the advertisement) that can be taken as "I'm done", while the central one, can be found as such, since it's about selecting an item (and only one) in a list. So I may says that's all about UI/UX.

Comment: No, selecting a device does not dismiss the view either. One can connect to a device, but one is truly stuck in the view.